# Install Ruby 2.0 with OpenSSL and ReadLine support

Tags: ruby

I have a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 VM, and I would like to install Ruby 2.0.0-p0. I am able to get Ruby installed easily enough, but I am unable to get gems to work.

```
$ gem install bundler
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I have open SSL installed, so I'm not exactly sure what the problem is.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libssl-dev is already the newest version.
libssl1.0.0 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Similarly,

```
$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
```

If I go back to the installation, there are two lines that concern me.

```
$ sudo make install
Failed to configure openssl. It will not be installed.
Failed to configure readline. It will not be installed.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

In your source location, `cd ext/openssl` and then `ruby extconf.rb`.  This will generate a makefile **in the ext/openssl directory**.  Simply `make && sudo make install` it to build the ruby *openssl* extension, and install the .so into the appropriate location.

Ditto `ext/readline` for readline support.

Then you should be able to `make` ruby properly.

**Edit**: in case I wasn't clear enough:

```
pushd ext/openssl
ruby extconf.rb
make && sudo make install
popd

pushd ext/readline
ruby extconf.rb
make && sudo make install
popd

make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Note: this answer is for manually building and installing Ruby and its extension modules. See @chris-d's answer for a pure apt-based answer.

Comment: I got stuck on the third line, trying to `make` in `ext/openssl`: `*** No rule to make target '/include/ruby.h', needed by 'ossl.o'.  Stop.` Same thing for `ext/readline`.

Comment: @ZX9 I had the same problem, the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29106131/981405) worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same issue, I had to install the following two packages

```
libssl-dev
libreadline-dev
```

in fact I found I had to install the following packages to get ruby 2.0.0 and postgres 9.2 to compile on ubuntu 13.04 with openssl and readline so I thought I would share them

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get install -y make g++
sudo apt-get install -y curl git-core python-software-properties
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential zlib1g-dev libyaml-dev libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libgdbm-dev libreadline6-dev libncurses5-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libpq-dev libffi-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

for me it was a case of missing dependencies.

i *thought* i had all the dependencies required to install ruby, but i too was getting an openSSL and readline error.

i attempted to install ruby with RVM without root privileges which failed but gave me a list of missing dependencies. i then installed the dependencies with a package manager. i then re-attempted to install ruby from source from the beginning, and everything worked OK

the dependencies that were missing, for me, were:

```
patch libyaml-devel autoconf gcc-c++ readline-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel automake libtool bison sqlite-devel
```

but they may be different for you.

**update:** i don't originally remember where exactly i found this list, but a quick search found similar lists on the following pages, which might also help you:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-centos-6-with-rvm

http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/install-ruby-on-rails-on-centos-ubuntu-fedora-from-source.html

Answer (score 0):

When installing ruby 2.0, it is possible that rubygems 2.0 installation did not complete ok, because of openssl. Make sure you provide a valid path to the openssl config file; you could:

```
find . -type f -name "openssl.cnf"
```

path is usually $HOME/.rvm/usr or $HOME/.rvm/usr/ssl

Then

```
[sudo] rvm reinstall ruby-2.0.0-p0 --with-openssl-dir=[openssl.cnf path] --verify-downloads 1
```

Make sure rubygems installation complete successfully. Might be a better way to fix that path without reinstalling, but this should do it.

Comment: I am trying an install without RVM or RBENV. Just compiling from sources. Hence the ./configure, make, and make install steps. Thank you, though.